# How can I extend the wait time for the watch command beyond 4200 or so seconds?

Tags: watch

I have encountered a limitation of the watch command.

Even though I specify `watch -n 14400` to run the command every 4 hours or so, the command executes every 4200 or so seconds, which is about an hour's worth of wait. Otherwise very useful command, is there a way to extend the range beyond 4200 seconds.

I think the limit comes from time being measured in microseconds and 4200 million micro seconds, and 4200 M is 2^32 or something.

Comment: Are you sure `watch` is the right command here? Maybe you want `at` or a `crontab` entry instead.

Comment: Or even `while true; do command; sleep 14400; done`, for less permanent setups.

Comment: The watch command is coming with procps and is *not* a bash internal. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: To add to @jw013's hack: `sleep` also takes human postfixes, so `sleep 4h` would seem fitting. I  made a [poor man's watch](https://gist.github.com/2427427) which might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `watch` from [busybox](http://busybox.net/): install the busybox package and then call it via

```
 busybox watch -n 14400 THE_COMMAND
```

In opposite to the normal `watch` coming with the procps package, it works internal with seconds (and not with microseconds).

But if you need such long periods, you should have at least a look at `cron` or `at` as Warren Young pointed out in his comment. With them, you can run commands in the background and do not need a terminal.

Comment: Hi, Thanks Everyone for answering. here's what I tried and what finally works for me: at - not existent on my host. cron - I really want interactive, terminal output at this point. while true; loop - got strange results (mind you the "command" is complicated and involves "less" where I think I got stuck). busybox - not installed on my host. poor man's watch, too complicated for me. What finally worked was to insert sleep 14400 as the one-before-last of the commands inside the watch command. Advantage, I got exactly the same output as with watch, but with an additional sleep 14400 delay.